# How do i check my Json

Tags: json, titanium

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator to develop an Android application..I getting an error while using **'ACS JSON'** .. I trying to use posts query, But i getting different kinds of array ..i need to check is whether the string is available or not before access..

For Example:

```
  "response": {
"posts": [
  {
    "id": "52e7800340b4b0aa134",
    "title": "test",
    "created_at": "2014-01-28T10:01:39+0000",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:59:54+0000",
    "content": "#hi all",
    "reviews_count": 3,
    "ratings_count": 3,
    "ratings_average": 3.67,
    "ratings_summary": {
      "5": 1,
      "3": 2
    },
    "user": {
      "id": "52e5e87f08a3e70b3309c3e3",
      "first_name": "aa",
      "last_name": "ss",
      "created_at": "2014-01-27T05:02:55+0000",
      "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:58:49+0000",
      "external_accounts": [

      ],
      "confirmed_at": "2014-01-27T05:02:55+0000",
      "username": "ss",
      "role": "a",
      "admin": "false"
    },
    "custom_fields": {
      "postedby": "aa",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "52e7908a3e70b3d0a9614",
    "title": "bb",
    "tags": [
      "sdf",
    ],
    "created_at": "2014-01-28T11:46:00+0000",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:09:17+0000",
    "content": "#hi@ #kWh v #sdf",
    "user": {
      "id": "52e5e87f08a3e70b3309c3e3",
      "first_name": "bb",
      "last_name": "bbc",
      "created_at": "2014-01-27T05:02:55+0000",
      "updated_at": "2014-01-30T11:58:49+0000",
      "external_accounts": [

      ],
      "confirmed_at": "2014-01-27T05:02:55+0000",
      "username": "b",
      "role": "b",
      "admin": "false"
    },
    "custom_fields": {
      "postedby": "b"
    }
  },
```

See I getting *ratings_count* in my first post..while trying access this inside for loop i getting error..

Now i need to check is whether the string is available or not before access..!

Comment: Your json is not valid one.

Comment: @Anand: I did't put my full Json..i just pasted sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var i in response.posts) {
    post = response.posts[i];
    if (post.ratings_count) {
        /* Do operations for post with ratings */
    } else {
        /* Do operations for post without ratings */
    }
}
```

This is pretty basic operation in JavaScript, so before you dive deeper into Titanium it's good to catch up with plain JS before.

Answer (score 1):

In titanium you can check anything whether it exist or not by using if statment.You can do this

```
if(ratingcount){

//Do here whatever you want to do

}
```

Thanks